# System Backup without User Data

Tags: windows-7, backup

I'm looking for a way to make a backup of my system without any of the user data. I know there are many programs for creating backups and system images but all of them I've seen so far always want to backup the whole system. Backing up everything isn't what I want though, my goal is to have a backup that has Windows and all the applications installed but no user data. Ideally, if I had a fatal crash I could restore this backup and I'd have a system with all my applications ready, all I'd need to do is setup my user profile.

Is there a way to do this or this type of backup not possible/not a good idea?

Comment: Easy, make the image _before_ you add your user data.

Comment: You should use ImageX. You can define folders/files to exclude. Check out: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766147%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: This is such a 'Windows' question. Don't mind me, I'm just here to watch it burn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research it seems a combination of Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 and ChrisinNL suggestions is the best answer:

Use a clean install and use ImageX and the provided Microsoft tools to create an image.